# Self-extensions of a skyscraper sheaf: algebra structure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $V$ be a smooth variety over a field $k$. For a point $x \in V$ we denote the skyscraper sheaf of length 1 by 
$$
k(x) = \mathcal{O}_x/m_x.
$$
Then by taking the Koszul resolution of $k(x)$ one can show that
$$
Ext^i(k(x),k(x)) \cong \wedge^i T_x V.
$$

Is this isomorphism an isomorphism of graded algebras? Where on the left we use Yoneda product and on the right the standard exterior product.

Comment: Hi, maybe Lemma 1.3.2. in Kuznetsov's and Markushevich's article "Symplectic structures on moduli spaces of sheaves via the Atiyah class" helps you to answer this question?

Comment: Yes, that Lemma is a generalization of my question, but their proof is "it is clear".

Comment: Okay, that is true. I found a better citation. It is the book: "Foundations of Grothendieck Duality for Diagrams of Schemes" by Lipman and Hashimoto. They explicitely state that the Yoneda algebra is isomorphic to the exterior algebra as graded algebras, it is Proposition 28.8.3. In their proof they reduce to the affine case and refer to a another result in a different book of Hashimoto ( :-) ), which can be read via Google books.

Comment: Thanks, I found the proof, it is what I expected. Although the reference is quite exotic for this simple fact.